# Xcode 12 Window Tabs + Document Tabs

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

I was using window tabs before document tabs announced to separate Interface Builder from documents to earn some time by avoiding reopening of storyboards.(I have a Late'13 MBP)
So one window tab for `Main.storyboard` and one or more window tab(s) for text documents like swift files.
And thanks to window tabs they allow me to select different pane configuration for each tab. To utilize screen usage I was closing left pane (Navigator) at Storyboard tab and closing right pane (Inspectors) at .swift tabs.
[image: storyboard tab]

[image: code files tab]

Then Xcode 12 arrived and document tabs announced. So I started to use window tabs + document tabs. Still one window tab for interface builder and one or more documents tabs for storyboards or nibs. Another window tab for text files and one or more documents tabs for .swift files or etc.
Navigator and Inspector panes usage were still same.

But at some point they changed a behavior of window tabs. Now pane configuration is not tab based, it is application based. So this is so frustrating for me to opening and closing panes every time when I navigate between tabs.

Do you have suggestion to change this pane configuration behavior?